# SonarQube rules not picked up by sonar-runner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have setup SonarQube 4.5.1 on Windows, backed by a SQL server (2012).  The analyzer is running on a Linux box.  I have changed the sonar.properties on the Linux box to point to the SQL server and the data is getting uploaded correctly.

I also have the web server configured correctly to query the data from the SQL server.

However, if I change the rules (add new rules, change rule values, etc), the setting changes are not reflected in my analyzer box.  Is there a configuration step that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be trivial.

In the sonar-runner.properties file under /etc/sonar-runner/conf folder, set the server.host.url correctly.

## ----- Default SonarQube server

sonar.host.url=http://sonar.webserver:80